# Django translation: add custom translation

Tags: django, translation

I have an application where users can fill a text field.
I would like "try" to translate it if the string that the user entered is in the `.po` *translation files*.

So in one of my detail views, I did something like:

```
class InterrogationDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Interrogation

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InterrogationDetailView, self)\
            .get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.object is not None:
            context[u'translated_word'] = {
                u'description': _(self.object.description),
            }
        return context
```

That's nice, it seems to work. So it searches in the `.po` files. So I'd like to add sentences, or words on my own in those `.po` files. When I try to add one translation that is *not* in my source files, when I call *makemessages* I get them commented like:

```
#~ msgid "I'm a test"
#~ msgstr "Godsmack - Cryin' like a b"
```

How to solve this? And if I'm not doing this the right way (I've read a lot about [django translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/)), what is the way to go?

Comment: I can't seem to find the duplicate but I've seen it suggested before just making a separate `.py` file that contains translations...

Comment: No reason to vote closing the question, it is perfectly valid and not subjective at all imo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20439571/977622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documentation mentions that `makemessages` is not capable of extracting translations for computed values, as happens in your example.

In order to have translations for strings that you retrieve from somewhere else you have to have them in your code as string literals. This can be achieved by the way @psychok7 suggests, creating a separate .py listing all those strings.

One way to automate this could be to write your custom `django-admin` command that will retrieve strings to be translated from database and put them into some file, locatable by `makemessages`, e.g. `.txt` with translation tags.