# Different languages in django WITHOUT using translation

Tags: django, internationalization

I want a project in english and spanish, but I want to have MY translations inst of using django's.

So, is it possible and practical?
Where would these copies be located and how do I switch betweem them in my templates?
How do I work with my database for translations?

Do you think django's translator works well and maybe I'd better use it?

Comment: Check out this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/20439571/1199464

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the "translator" is. Django won't translate your own content; it just has default translations for the built in functionality such as the admin. There are comprehensive docs on how to extend this for your own objects.